# Game Interface Design - VBO or Immediate Mode?

Tags: opengl, user-interface, vbo

I've been developing a 2d RPG based on the LWJGL alongside with Java 1.6 for 3 months now. My next goal is to write all of the non-game-ish stuff. This includes menus, text input boxes, buttons and things like the inventory and character information screens. As I am a Computer Engineering student, I'm trying to write everything on my own (except, of course, for the OpenGL part of the LWJGL) so that I "test" myself on the writing of a simple 2d game engine.
I know that making such things from scratch requires basically mapping textures to quads (like the buttons), writing stuff on them and testing mouse/keyboard events which trigger other events inside the code.

The doubt I have is: should I use VBO's (as I'm using for the actual game rendering) or Immediate Mode when rendering such elements? I don't really know if Immediate Mode would be such a drop on performance. Another point is: do the interface elements have to be updated as fast as the game itself? I don't think so, because nothing is actually moving... Are actual games made like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediate Mode is more straightforward for the task, you would not need to take care about caching and controls composition/batching. Performance dropoff is not that big, unless you render a lot of text (thousands of letters) with each glyph in a separate `glBegin..glEnd`. If you don't use VBO anywhere else I would recommend trying it out for text output and doing everything else in easier Immediate Mode.

GUI elements might not change as often as game state does, but there's a catch - you could need to update them each time there's a cursor interaction (e.g. button gets `OnMouseOver` event and needs to be rendered with a highlight). These kind of events may happen very frequently, so thats why rendering may be needed at a full speed.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the answer. Is rendering text a stressing task because there is too much texture switching?

Comment: Ideally you will have all your text glyphs in one atlas, so there's no texture switching. The load is due to the fact that you need to parse each text line letter by letter. Take a look at this SO page, there are maybe few dozens of controls, but amount of letters is much higher.